# Angular http-server page refresh 404s

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app with a controller routed like so:

**controllers/favorites.js**

```
...
$stateProvider.state('app.favorites' {url: '/favorites'} ...);
```

**index.html**

```
...
<a ui-sref="app.favorites"> ...
```

When you click the `<a>` tag, it takes you to the proper controller, routes the page to `/favorites` and everything is dandy. However, when you refresh the page, I get a 404 (the url is still `/favorites`)

Any idea why this is? I'm running the app using `http-server`, but I also get the same issue with `python -mSimpleHTTPServer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to change the page location without reloading the page via the DOM's 'history' API. Your backend doesn't automatically know or care about the way a frontend app does this.

After your Angular app has navigated the browser to the location `/favorites`, when you refresh you will hit your backend at the location `/favorites`.

Does your backend react to a GET request at `/favorites`? Perhaps it should! It's generally considered 'best practice' to allow users to refresh without 404ing.

This is perhaps a good time to break DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself); both the frontend and the backend need knowledge of your app's routes.

Answer (score -1):

It probably has something to do with how angular loads the views. When you hit the index page it loads all the views at the same time. I think the problem is since you're refreshing on the same page it just doesn't know to reload the views.

I would look into running using grunt serve for a dev server as it auto refreshes every time you edit a file and it can be quite handy.

Comment: http-server also has auto reload